# stuck when trying to run ls, ll command

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I'm new in Linux. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04. It work for a while without any problem. Yesterday, I got a strange problem: when I logged in using my account and try to run `ls` or `ll`, the cursor jumped down without showing results and got stuck. I press enter and the only thing it does just jumping lower. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I get `^C`. I noticed also that I can't open my folder in the GUI. But if I open new terminal and log in as root, I can run `ls`, `ll`, and other commands.

This happens in my home directory only. If I run `ls /etc`, I get a listing of the `/etc` directory.

And something more: if I open a terminal and without running any command and shut it down, the terminal windows just disappear. But if I open the terminal and run `ls` for my home directory, the cursor goes down, as I described before, and if I try to close the terminal window I get a message that "the process is still running in this terminal. Closing the terminal will kill it".

Comment: Please provide more information (by editing your question). Does this happen no matter what directory you are in or only your home directory? Does it happen if you, for example, type "ls /etc"? Does it happen if you type "/bin/ls"? What does "ls | cat -A" show as far as filenames?

Comment: Thanks #jpezz for your answer! Answering to your questions: Yes, it happens in my home directory only. If I perform ls /etc I get the list of etc directory.

Comment: And something more: if I open a terminal and without running any command shut it down the terminal windows just disappear. But if I open the terminal and run ls for my home directory, cursor goes down, as i described before, and if i try to close the terminal window I get a message that "the process is still running in this terminal. Closing the terminal will kill it".

Comment: Sounds like a problem in home directory. Possible corrupt file name or corrupt structure. Try executing "ls -q|more" to display non-printing characters as "?" then sends  to "more" which gives you a screen at a time. Also does the "ls" command in your home directory when run by root work? That's not clear from you root comment.